# Why does NaN != undefined?

Tags: javascript, variables

According to the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals):

> The undefined value converts to NaN when used in numeric context.

So why do both of the following equate to true?:

```
NaN != undefined
NaN !== undefined
```

I could understand `Nan !== undefined` as the variable type would be different...

Comment: Because `NaN` is *not equal to anything*, even to its self. Thus, an `isNaN` function is created for it. Makes no sense using comparisons on it.

Answer (score 14):

NaN is **by definition** "***Not a Number***"

That does not mean it is undefined -- it *is* clearly **defined** -- but undefined in a sense that it is **not** a number.

Comment: I know the definition, it's the manner in which it's explained on the mozilla docs: "The undefined **value** converts to NaN when used in numeric context." Which leads me to think that it's undefined, but cast as a number...

Comment: @oodavid the same holds for string casts :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because, according to [Section 4.3.23 of ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.23) `NaN` is defined as:

> number value that is a IEEE 754 “Not-a-Number” value

So it's a number and not something undefined or null. The value is explained further in [Section 8.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)

> ...; to ECMAScript code, all NaN values are indistinguishable from each other.

Equality comparisons with `NaN` are defined in [Section 11.9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3):

> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>   If Type(x) is Number, then:
>
> If x is NaN, return false.
>
> If y is NaN, return false.

For the purpose of comparison you should use `isNaN()` instead:

```
isNaN(NaN)
// true
```

**Update**

The value of `+undefined` is not-a-number, but it's a number nonetheless (albeit with a special value) and therefore not undefined. Just like how casting `undefined` to a string yields a string value that's defined.